# PyQGIS load QML style from plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I need to apply a .qml style to a layer on my map as part of a Python plugin. I gather that this can be done via `QgsMapLayer.loadNamedStyle()`. The problem I have is that my .qml file is stored within my plugin directory and I can't figure out how to reference the path at runtime.

The plugin is in my user plugin directory (/home/[user]/.qgis2/python/plugins/[plugindirectory]) not the main QGIS plugin directory, so I can't get a reference via `qgsApplication.pluginPath()`.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Would the answer for this [post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33461/qgis-how-to-load-feature-qml-styles-from-python/33464#33464) help where you set a fixed path to your .qml file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import os

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Now path variable stores your path to the plugin directory which contains plugin.py:

```
>>> path
>>> "/home/[user]/.qgis2/python/plugins/[plugindirectory]"
```

Answer (score 8):

The shortest way to get the path to your plugin directory:

```
import os

plugin_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

So the path of your .qml file could be:

```
qml_path = plugin_path + "/myFile.qml"
```

Finally, you can load the .qml file to your QgsVectorLayer:

```
myLayer.loadNamedStyle(qml_path)
```